Why would "daría" work here and not "daré" in this context?
Nota: Lo siento si sería más aceptable para preguntar en español en total, aunque puedo tratar de añadir una versión traducida tan mejor cómo podré si ese es el caso.
So I have been trying to learn Spanish for the past few years because I had thought that it might be nice to learn another language and I thought that Spanish would be a good place to start. I have been doing this by first finding texts that teach me the necessary concepts that I want to learn (whether it be vocabulary or a new verb conjugation), and then finding online practices to help me remember those concepts better.
I have been teaching myself the conditional tense recently, and although I have finished this practice (for when to use the future or conditional tense of a verb), I am confused about the answer for the 15th sentence:

Yo en tu lugar no le ___ (dar) otra oportunidad.

It seemed to me that "daré" would be correct here because it seems like the sentence talks about someone (in this case the speaker) saying that they wouldn't be giving something another opportunity in someone else's place. However when checking my answers afterwards, it said that this should actually instead be "daría", but I'm not really sure why.
Question:

Why would "daría" work here and not "daré" in this context?


Only "daría" works there because you cannot be in the other person's place, so the condition is unreal and so is the result:

Si yo estuviera en tu lugar (NO estoy en tu lugar), no le daría otra oportunidad => Yo en tu lugar no le daría otra oportunidad

